# Order Bibliography alphabetically (author and titles)

Tags: bibtex, sorting, jurabib

I'm writing a paper using `jurabib`. The problem I have is that in the bibliography the entries are well sorted by author, but where an author has more than one entry these are not in alphabetical order. I guess that they are sorted by the type of entry (book, article, phdthesis). 
How can I get the entries sorted by author AND title in alphabetical order?

```
\documentclass[fontsize=10pt, fleqn, pdftex, version=last, x11names,pointlessnmbers]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[howcited=normal, authorformat=smallcaps]{jurabib}
```

These would be the `.bib` file entries:

```
@article{PBadh,
Author = {Peter B{\"o}ckli},
Date-Added = {2013-09-23 16:44:10 +0200},
Date-Modified = {2013-09-23 16:46:41 +0200},
Howcited = {\textsc{B{\"o}ckli}, Ad hoc Publizit{\"a}t},
Journal = {\textsc{B{\"u}hler} (Hrsg.), Informationspflichten des Unternehmens im Gesellschafts- und B{\"o}rsenrecht,},
Keywords = {GC 89029},
Pages = {87-XX},
Shorttitle = {Ad hoc Publizit{\"a}t},
Title = {Ad hoc Publizit{\"a}t und Insiderstrafnorm: Nach und Feinschliff f{\"u}r das Informationsrecht des kapitalmarktes},
Year = {Bern/Stuttgart/Wien 2003}}

@article{PBInsich,
Author = {Peter B{\"o}ckli},
Date-Added = {2013-08-26 10:44:52 +0200},
Date-Modified = {2013-09-20 10:12:18 +0200},
Howcited = {\textsc{B{\"o}ckli}, Insichgesch{\"a}fte},
Journal = {Gesellschafts- und Kapitalmarktrecht},
Pages = {354-371},
Shorttitle = {Insichgesch{\"a}fte},
Title = {Insichgesch{\"a}fte und Interessenkonflikte im Verwaltungsrat: Heutige Rechtslage und Blick auf den kommenden Art. 717a E-OR},
Volume = {(3)},
Year = {2012}}

@book{PBIns,
Author = {Peter B{\"o}ckli},
Date-Added = {2013-08-20 09:30:03 +0200},
Date-Modified = {2013-09-20 10:12:03 +0200},
Howcited = {\textsc{B{\"o}ckli}, Insiderstrafrecht},
Publisher = {Z{\"u}rich},
Shorttitle = {Insiderstrafrecht},
Title = {Insiderstrafrecht und Verantwortung des Verwaltungsrates},
Year = {1989}}

 @article{PBBP,
Author = {Peter B{\"o}ckli},
Date-Added = {2013-08-26 11:27:44 +0200},
Date-Modified = {2013-09-20 10:11:50 +0200},
Howcited = {\textsc{B{\"o}ckli}, R{\"u}ckkauf nichtkotierter eigener Aktien},
Journal = {Der Schweizer Treuh{\"a}nder},
Pages = {575-586},
Shorttitle = {R{\"u}ckkauf nichtkotierter eigener Aktien},
Title = {Neun Regeln der ''Best Practice'' f{\"u}r den R{\"u}ckkauf nichtkotierter eigener Aktien},
Volume = {(6-7)},
Year = {2001}}

 @book{PB,
Author = {Peter B{\"o}ckli},
Date-Added = {2013-07-10 11:04:12 +0200},
Date-Modified = {2013-09-20 10:11:12 +0200},
Edition = {4},
Howcited = {\textsc{B{\"o}ckli}, Schweizer Aktienrecht},
Publisher = {Z{\"u}rich},
Shorttitle = {Schweizer Aktienreecht},
Title = {Schweizer Aktienrecht},
Year = {2009}}
```

As I would expect I should have the following order:

> 1. PBadh
> 2. PBInsich
> 3. PBIns
> 4. PBBP
> 5. PB

As it turns out, that's exactly the order I have in the bib-file. However in the bibliography I get the following order:

> 1. PBIns
> 2. PBBP
> 3. PB
> 4. PBInsich
> 5. PBadh

Comment: Can you provide us with a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/) ideally with some wrongly-ordered bibliography entries an the expected output?

Comment: The entries seem to be ordered by year (`PBadh` does not contain a proper year [`Bern/Stuttgart/Wien 2003`], so it is sorted at the end).

Comment: And how do I get them ordered by title?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default `jurabib` sorts the works by `author` and then by `year`.

To sort the items by author and then `title` you need to modify the file `jurabib.bst`, locate it on your computer (use `kpsewhich jurabib.bst` to find it, if you need), copy it to a location LaTeX can find it, rename it to say, `myjurabib.bst`.

Open the file `myjurabib.bst` and locate the `FUNCTION {presort}`; go to the following block

```
type$ "archival" = not
     { "    "
       *
       year field.or.null sortify
       *
       "    "
       *
       title field.or.null
       sort.format.title
       *
     }
```

change it to

```
type$ "archival" = not
   { 
     "    "
     *
     title field.or.null
     sort.format.title
     *
     "    "
     *
     year field.or.null sortify
     *
   }
```

In your document, you then use `\bibliographystyle{myjurabib}` instead of `\bibliographystyle{jurabib}`.